# Functions with cardinals as domain

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

How do we actually define a function with cardinals as domain? For example, take domain of the function as $\aleph_1$. Do we define it for all cardinal numbers strictly less than $\aleph_1$?

Comment: Your suggestion seems to require that the domain of the function is closed downward, but you may not want this. For instance you may be interested in functions with domain $\omega=\aleph_0$ but you may also be interested in functions with domain $\omega \setminus\{10\}$.

Comment: Can you give a specific example which you are interested in? As stated the question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

There are two fine points here.

1. Cardinals are ordinals (in the context of $\aleph$ numbers anyway). When we say that we define a function on $\aleph_1$ it might be the case that we define a function on the cardinals below $\aleph_1$, or it might be the case that we are interested in all the ordinals below $\aleph_1$.
2. Cardinals are sets. Of course, the collection of all cardinals is not a set. But each cardinal is a set. So we can define a function on that set very much like we define a function on any other set.

   One can use the inherent structure of cardinals and ordinals, or one can ignore that, and give a different structure if needs be.

And remember that there are many functions on an infinite set, and those need not be definable. They simply exist out there, in the set theoretical universe.

Comment: Are you considering a cardinal number as the set of all cardinals strictly less than it? (As you said that cardinals are sets)

Comment: No, it is a set of all the **ordinals** of smaller cardinality. Note that the only cardinals smaller than $\aleph_1$ are finite and $\aleph_0$, so there are countably many of them; but if you consider ordinals then the set of countable ordinals does have size $\aleph_1$.

Comment: I haven't been knighted yet. But you're welcome.

Comment: Are the only cardinals smaller than $\aleph_1$ finite and $\aleph_0$ in ZF$\neg$C?

Comment: @Ian: Any cardinal smaller than an $\aleph$ is finite or an $\aleph$ itself. So there's really no difference if you add or remove choice (or its negation) in that matter.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase: in ZF$\neg$C are there cardinals which are comparable to neither $\aleph_1$ nor $\aleph_0$? (I am not well-trained in set theory, I just know that there are cardinals that are not alephs in ZF$\neg$C.)

Comment: @Ian: It is consistent, but it is not provable just from $\lnot\sf AC$.